# How do I detect button presses from a ble device?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

I've been working on an app in flutter that connects to a ble device and responds to button presses from the device. I've tried various packages and frameworks and none works. I decided to try nrf connect to test the devices and it connects to a all the devices but even with subscribing to the notify/indicate characteristics button taps don't do anything. The devices are the minew b10 and two satech beacons. Does anyone have any ideas on what to do?

I'm testing the app on android 12 using a package called flutter_blue.
The website and documentation for the b10 are below

website: https://www.minew.com/product/b10-smart-emergency-button/

docs:
https://docs.beaconyun.com/Android/Android_BeaconPlus_Software_Development_Kit_Guide.html#design-instructions

```dart
  Future<void> setListener(BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic) async {
    print(characteristic.isNotifying);
    await characteristic.setNotifyValue(true);
    print(characteristic.isNotifying);
    try {
      // while (connectText.value == 'DISCONNECT') {
      characteristic.value.listen((event) {
        print('event: $event');
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('error: $e');
    }
  }
```

This is the section of the code responsible for subscribing to the notify/indicate characteristic.

Comment: Can you share links to the documentation of the relevant devices, the relevant parts of your code, and any logs/traces? Also let us know on what platform/OS you are testing? And does it work with the manufacturers’ own apps?

Comment: I only have documentation for one of the devices, the minew b10. Below are the website and the link to the sdk

https://www.minew.com/product/b10-smart-emergency-button/

https://docs.beaconyun.com/Android/Android_BeaconPlus_Software_Development_Kit_Guide.html#design-instructions

I'm testing the app on android 12

Comment: Please edit your question to add the relevant details.

Comment: There is nothing in that documentation about the button (other than using it to restore a sensor set to not connectable or shut down)…

Comment: That's my problem, I know how ble works and these devices do follow the correct protocols but when it comes on to the notifying when the buttons are pressed or in the case of the b10 maintaining a connection for more than 10s I am stumped.  I've even talked to the developer of one of them and it wasn't any help. The sdk for that one targets android 4 and is almost 5 years old. I have done my best to update it and fix any bugs but it crashes instantly anyway.

Comment: Is there actually a characteristic for the button? Or maybe the button press is only published through advertising data? Is their own app able to show anything about that button?